# Converting String to Int in Java using Arrays

Tags: java

I'm trying to convert the string values to integers, however whenever i do this, it gives me the ASCI value of the character instead of the actual typed string.

Example:

a user inputs "11101" on there keyboard to a string variable named binary

```
for(int i = 0; i < binary.length(); i++){
storage[i] = Integer.valueOf(binary.charAt(i));
}
```

if I look at the values of storage[i], i will see only the ASCI values of the numbers, and not the actual 1's or 0's

Comment: Why? You don't need an array to store an integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < binary.length(); i++){
    storage[i] = Integer.valueOf(binary.substring(i, i + 1));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `Integer.parseInt(str,radix)` method.

```
int no=Integer.parseInt("11101",2);

//or

int no=Integer.parseInt("11101");
```

Comment: I never knew about the radix before, thank you so much. I will get a great deal of use from this.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick.

```
storage[i] = Integer.parseInt( binary.charAt(i));
```

Comment: Except it will not fail on invalid input such as: 110011911

Comment: Thank you for the example, i had actually tried this one, but still got the same results, but thanks for the info :)

Comment: @PlexQ there was no mention of validation

Comment: It returns the asci value of the input, not the typed value

Answer (score 2):

```
for(int i = 0; i < binary.length(); i++){
  storage[i] = Integer.parseInt(binary.charAt(i), 2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i = 0; i < binary.length(); i++){
    storage[i] = binary.charAt(i) - '0';
}
```